# GroupedAttachments Macro Property Group pluralized?

Tags: macros, grouping, attachment, kentico

I'm implementing grouped attachments as per https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+grouped+document+attachments, and need to find out via a macro whether the group has attachments or not.

Only managed to realize that the name of the group "PortfolioGallery" is pluralized to "PortfolioGalleries" for some reason...

[image]

Is this because Gallery is some kind of reserved word in macro names, and gets pluralized always, or is this a 'feature' for the GroupedAttachments macro property? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a feature and it gets pluralized always.

Method [ObjectRepository.GetNicePropertyName](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/M_CMS_DataEngine_ObjectRepository_3_GetNicePropertyName.htm) provides this functionality.

Comment: Is that something we should expected for all "computed"/runtime macro property names? Or is it just for the GroupedAttachments?